# Multiple targets and multiple provisioning profiles in XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, provisioning

I am creating two targets of my app (a free and a paid version) and cannot make XCode use the proper provisioning profile for the debug built of one of these versions. It attempts to use the profile of the paid one for both version, and obviously fails since the bundle ID does not match.

In the 'Get Info' build settings for each target I can select the provisioning profile explicitly only if the configuration is set to 'Distribution'. That's not very helpful because I use a wildcard profile for distribution anyway. As soon as I switch to 'Debug' settings, it only lets me select the signing certificate, like "iPhone Developer: My Name (cert id here)", but not the specific provisioning profile, like "iPhone Developer: My Name (cert id here) profile-id-here".

I tried pasting the "iPhone Developer: My Name (cert id here) profile-id-here" manually by selecting "Other" in the code signing identity field, but it tells me:

Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer: My Name (cert id here) profile-id-here' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

This does not make a lot of sense, since the certificate used for both profiles is the same and works fine for the other one.

I think it was not like that when I tried it in XCode 3.2.2 but having updated to 3.2.3 for the iOS4 support, that's the only thing I can get.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am having the same problem. I see that a lot of time has passed since your attempt... thanks.

Comment: I find that the sort of easiest option was to clear out all the info from XCode that you entered manually and let it manage your provisioning etc automatically. I don't recall how I fixed this particular issue, but I had other problems with mismatched certs (specifically when I renewed membership and the old and new certs were clashing) - I just let XCode do as much as it could - it seems to work more often than not.

Answer (score 0):

You might have accidentally moved your certs elsewhere in the keychain.
The certs should be inside the "login" keychain and not system or elsewhere

Comment: Certs? I only use one cert! Do I have to have only one provisioning profile per cert?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the Active Target AND Active Executable to the free version?